# Flask-Firebase app on Heroku not getting env vars

Tags: python, firebase, heroku, flask, environment-variables

I'm having trouble making a Flask app that uses Firebase to run.
It seems like the Firebase Credentials api does not take the env vars even after they have been printed!

Heres de app code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
""" PixelCode PDF generation application"""

from io import BytesIO
from os import environ
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, send_file, abort, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore, credentials

load_dotenv()

APP = Flask(__name__)
CORS(APP)

ENV_KEYS = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "private_key_id": environ["FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID"],
    "private_key": environ["FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY"],
    "client_email": environ["FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL"],
    "client_id": environ["FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID"],
    "token_uri": environ["FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI"],
    "project_id": environ["FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID"],
}

print("ENV KEYS:", ENV_KEYS)

CREDENTIALS = credentials.Certificate(ENV_KEYS)

firebase_admin.initialize_app(
    CREDENTIALS, {'databaseURL': environ["FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL"]}
)

DB = firestore.client()

# Trimmed for brevity...

@APP.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def get_home():
    return render_template_string("<h2>PixelCode GoDocu Services</h2>")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
    # can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml.
    # Flask's development server will automatically serve static files in
    # the "static" directory. See:
    # http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files. Once deployed,
    # App Engine itself will serve those files as configured in app.yaml.
    APP.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=environ.get('PORT', 8080), debug=True)
```

On dev/local environment (my pc) the app works fine using a *.env* file.
I have set up the env vars on heroku too.

When the app gets deployed, the *print* statement prints all the env vars fine.
After that, the app crashes with this error:

> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349817+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-04 14:11:33 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349821+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349824+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 97, in **init**
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349826+00:00 app[web.1]:     json_data, scopes=_scopes)
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349829+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 193, in from_service_account_info
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349832+00:00 app[web.1]:     info, require=['client_email', 'token_uri'])
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349834+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 54, in from_dict
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349836+00:00 app[web.1]:     signer = crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_info(data)
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349838+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/crypt/base.py", line 115, in from_service_account_info
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349840+00:00 app[web.1]:     info.get(_JSON_FILE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID))
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349842+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/crypt/_python_rsa.py", line 174, in from_string
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349844+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ValueError('No key could be detected.')
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349847+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: No key could be detected.
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349849+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349851+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349858+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349860+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349862+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349864+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349866+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349868+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349871+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349873+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349875+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349877+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349879+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349881+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349883+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349885+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349887+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349889+00:00 app[web.1]:     **import**(module)
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349891+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 30, in
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349893+00:00 app[web.1]:     CREDENTIALS = credentials.Certificate(ENV_KEYS)
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349895+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 100, in **init**
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349897+00:00 app[web.1]:     'Caused by: "{0}"'.format(error))
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.349900+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Failed to initialize a certificate credential. Caused by: "No key could be detected."
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.350466+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-04 14:11:33 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
>
> 2019-12-04T14:11:33.625273+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-12-04 14:11:33 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles on a similar issue (not limited to heroku & firebase),
when shells (some) parse environmental variables, they escape special characters hence passing them as literal. 
for the case above, When you execute the command `heroku config -s`, you will notice that for the `FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY` characters, `\n` is replaced with `\\n`.

To fix, just replace `\\n` with `\n` in your code. See below

```
ENV_KEYS = {
"type": "service_account",
"private_key_id": environ["FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID"],
"private_key": environ["FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY"].replace("\\n", "\n"),
"client_email": environ["FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL"],
"client_id": environ["FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID"],
"token_uri": environ["FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI"],
"project_id": environ["FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID"],
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, I was facing the same issue